# git command not found

Tags: rhel, git

I had to install git from source on RHEL. After installation the git command is shown to be in  `/usr/local/bin/git` when trying the `whereis` command.This path is available in `$PATH` also.

When I type git it still says "Command not found."
How to resolve this?

EDIT : output of various commands

```
$type git
type: Command not found.

$which git
git: Command not found.

$ls -l /usr/local/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x 112 root users 5851488 Mar 15 20:07 /usr/local/bin/git

$whereis git
git: /usr/local/bin/git

$echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

EDIT: It works now but do not know why

I disconnected the telnet connection and logged in again few minutes back and find that the git command works. I am not sure what caused it to start working. This is confusing.

Comment: Please add the `type git`, `which git`, `ls -l /usr/local/bin/git` outputs.

Comment: @manatwork please see the edit.

Comment: @Marco added the output of echo $PATH.

Comment: I guess @manatwork meant `file` and not `type` ;-) so he wants (and I too) to see the output of `file /usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: @Huygens, no I meant `type`, to find out whether there is an alias or function with the same name.

Comment: @manatwork ho sorry I did not not that command.

Comment: @Huygens, `type` is a shell builtin in `dash`, `bash` and `zsh`. In case you use `ksh`, you may have a good excuse for not knowing it. (In my `ksh` there is just an alias to `whence` with the name `type`. Not sure how widespread is such setting.) http://pastebin.com/VzScxzRg

Comment: I don't believe RHEL doesn't include the `git` suite among its packages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error messages you're using (t)csh. It would help to mention it in your question, especially as you're showing `$` as your prompt, and that's traditionally a Bourne prompt, not a csh prompt.

`type` is a builtin in Bourne-style shell. It doesn't exist in csh. When you run `type git`, it tells you that the `type` command is not found.

Many shells keep information about the location of commands in the search path in a cache. I don't know if any version of csh caches negative lookups, but it seems that yours does. Run the command `rehash` to refresh the cache. When you start a new shell instance, it has a fresh cache and so doesn't remember that `git` was not present earlier.

Comment: Hi Gilles, I should have mentioned the shell. Sorry for that. But I get $ in the prompt for both bash and tcsh. in tsch it is [username@systemname]$ format and in bash it is bash-3.2$ format.

Comment: I think this is the closest possible explanation to what happened. I will try to recreate this and verify and get back. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that, as in [this thread](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=120426), your shell hasn't changed from the one you are supposed to get:

> I have just found that my shell got changed to csh and it was creating the problem.

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep ^"$USER" /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/csh
```

> I changed it to bash and the problem was resolved!

```
[root@localhost ~]# type export
export is a shell builtin
```

That would explain why you get a '`type: Command not found.`' error message.

> I experimented with these commands:

```
[root@localhost ~]# csh
[root@localhost ~]# type export
type: Command not found.
[root@localhost ~]# bash
[root@localhost ~]# type export
export is a shell builtin
[root@localhost ~]# grep ^"$USER" /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Changing the shell to bash causes the 'type' command to work. The git command works now even without going into bash. Do not know why! Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The most probable reason is that you have the correct `PATH` but not the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The latest `git` executable is a binary file which is dynamically linked. When you followed the installation instructions, it probably placed libraries (`.so` files) in `/usr/local/lib`, you need to add this path to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Try it and then run git:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
git
```

If that does not work, could you provide the output of `ldd /usr/local/bin/git`. Thanks.

*PS: if the solution worked, you need to add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH line to your `.bash_profile`*